# Why Can´t I hide the Title bar on a Progress bar?

Tags: excel, vba, progress-bar, userform

I am trying to use some code from [here](https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/beautiful-vba-progress-bar-with-step-by-step-instructions/).
I have checked in some programmings forums and it seems to be ok. But I am getting a 438 error on showing an Userform used as progress bar. I don´t have any knowledge at all on how to use libraries (It is my first time).

The Header Code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

' FROM https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/beautiful-vba-progress-bar-with-step-by-step-instructions/
Public Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Public Const WS_CAPTION = &HC00000
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                           ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar _
                           Lib "user32" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA _
                           Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                           ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function GetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function SetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                           ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function DrawMenuBar _
                           Lib "user32" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function FindWindowA _
                           Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                           ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
```

Procedure to hide the Title bar

```
Sub HideTitleBar(frm As Object)
    Dim lngWindow As Long
    Dim lFrmHdl As Long

    lFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    lngWindow = GetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
    lngWindow = lngWindow And (Not WS_CAPTION)
    Call SetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE, lngWindow)
    Call DrawMenuBar(lFrmHdl)
End Sub
```

When I try to show the Userform I got a constant 438 error on line: `lFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, frm.Caption)`. I did not find why.

The Macro I have created to call this Userform:

```
Sub Delete_Zero()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim pctdone As Single


'(Step 1) Display your Progress Bar
ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
ufProgress.Show vbModeless

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        If Cells(i, j).Value2 = 0 Or Cells(i, j).Value2 = "" Then
            Cells(i, j).ClearContents
        End If
    Next j
    '(Step 2) Update Progress Bar
    pctdone = i / LastRow
    With ufProgress
        .LabelCaption.Caption = "Processing Row " & i & " of " & LastRow
        .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
    End With
    ufProgress.Repaint
    '(Step 3) Unload Progress Bar
    If i = LastRow Then Unload ufProgress
Next i

End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE 1:
I forgot to attach the code in the Userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Height = Me.Height - 10
    HideTitleBar.HideTitleBar Me
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot the Userform Code. Edited. This procedure is called from the Userform itself in order to hide the Title Bar. `"Delete Zero"` procedure it is taking too much time to delete all zero and "" values so I need to find some other way. That´s why I introduce this bar. In normal use, I don´t want to allow that the user can stop the procedure or close this progress bar. It is the first time that I am trying to use a progress bar. My previous trials, as they are having too much activity applying formats, as soon as I keep Application.ScreenUpdating = False, the progress bar didn´t work.

Comment: Why don't you just disable the close button? And there are other ways to prevent a macro from completing (such as ctrl + pause) that is difficult to circumvent.

Comment: And your progress bar "not working" is what I assume to actually be "not updating". People use `DoEvents` for various reasons, but the actual usage for this is to redraw your userform. So if your progress bar is not moving, then add a `DoEvents` line in your code to allow it to redraw itself.

Comment: My users have no idea of Ctrl+Pause Combo, so I was thinking in something more obvious. My previous approaches were with a custom chart that I can not refresh (as much as I know) with a DoEvents. You are right and I forgot to implement in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to prevent a user from clicking the `X` close button, then you don't need to jump through a bunch of hoops to hide the title bar. Simply capture the event and cancel the request.

In your userform code module, paste this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

And that's all there is to it.

---

Want to make it more sophisticated? Well, you can prompt the user first.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    if Inputbox("If you are sure you want to stop the procedure, please type the " & _
                                                    "word 'STOP'") = "STOP" then
        Cancel = False

    Else

        Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I like it. It is much better to not to hide the Title bar and capture the close button. I did not think on it. Thanks